# C++ storing a reference to an objects own function

Tags: c++, qt, function, progress-bar

**Problem**:

I'm trying to create a way to dynamically call different functions based on given input by the user in a C++ class. I'm trying to avoid doing this with a bunch of if statements because it would add a lot of complexity to my code. What I'm trying to do is store references in a map so that I can just loop through it and execute the stored functions.

**Current Setup**:

Currently I have this working but its using static method calls which I do not like as I have to set a bunch of static references to things the method needs, or make a ton of getters to private variables. I'm stuck in static hell.

Here is some code (Don't have my actual code on me so I rewrote what I think I have. Some syntax might be wrong but I have it compiling and working on my test machine)

```
typedef void (*functocall)(void) funcRef;

class Installer {
    struct Step {
        QString id,
        QString message,
        funcRef func
    }

    enum INSTALL_TYPE {
        APP_INSTALL,
        FILESYSTEM_INSTALL
        BOTH_INSTALL,
        ...
    }

public:
    void addStep(QString id, QString message, funcRef func) {
        Step step;
        step.id = id;
        step.message = message;
        step.func = func;
    }

    void nextStep() {
        // calls next in the map
        m_steps[m_currStep].func();
        m_currStep++;
    }

    void run(INSTALL_TYPE type) {

        // Storing in a map lets me define the entire process for all install types in one method. Also can mix methods between processes if needed
        // Also using steps to keep track of overall progess (currStep / m_steps.size())
        // Also lets me show the user all of the steps that will occur for this install
        // Basically is for creating a progress bar on a web interface and sending it percentages and a message

        if(type == APP_INSTALL || type == BOTH_INSTALL)
        {
            addStep("upload", "Uploading files", &Installer::uploadAppFiles);
        }

        if(type == FILESYSTEM_INSTALL || type == BOTH_INSTALL)
        {
            addStep("upload", "Uploading files", &Installer::uploadFileSystemFiles);
            addStep("extract", "Uploading files", &Installer::extractTar);
        }

        if(type == APP_INSTALL || type == BOTH_INSTALL)
        {
            addStep("install", "Install app", &Installer::installAppFiles);
        }

        if(type == FILESYSTEM_INSTALL || type == BOTH_INSTALL)
        {
            addStep("install", "Install file system", &Installer::installFileSystemFiles);
        }

        addStep("cleanup", "Cleanup system", &Installer::cleanup);

        addStep("reboot", "Reboot system", &Installer::reboot);
    }

    static void uploadAppFiles() {
        ...
    }

    static void uploadFileSystemFiles() {
        ...
    }

    ... other static methods

private:
    QList<Step> m_steps;

    int m_currStep;
}
```

**Preferred solution**:

What I'd really prefer to do is store references to non static methods inside of my installer class. I only need this object to be able to call its own internal methods so I can assure that the object will always exist.

I've looked into std::function but could not get it to work as **I don't have c++11** which I believe is required? **I also cannot use boost::function** as I do not want to add boost to my project. I already am using QT so if there's something in QT that can do this easily I would prefer that.

Originally I was doing this all on the client side through Javascript which was super easy, I'm sort of regretting moving it into C++ haha.

Comment: Are you saying that you need **a pointer to a member function?**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare a *member function pointer* type which has a different syntax to normal function pointers. Also you obviously have to supply the object when calling member functions through member function pointers.

```
//forward declare class
class Installer;
typedef void (Installer::*funcRef)(); // member function pointer
//            ^^^^^^^^^ <-- mentions the class it is a member of

class Installer {
    struct Step {
        QString id;
        QString message;
        funcRef func; // member function
    };

    enum INSTALL_TYPE {
        APP_INSTALL,
        FILESYSTEM_INSTALL,
        BOTH_INSTALL,
    };

public:
    void addStep(QString id, QString message, funcRef func) {
        Step step;
        step.id = id;
        step.message = message;
        step.func = func;
    }

    void nextStep() {
        // supply objects to member function pointer call
        // using this->*
        (this->*m_steps[m_currStep].func)();
    //   ^^^^ <- supplies the object the member is to be called on
        m_currStep++;
    }

    void run(INSTALL_TYPE type) {

        // Storing in a map lets me define the entire process for all install types in one method. Also can mix methods between processes if needed
        // Also using steps to keep track of overall progress (currStep / m_steps.size())
        // Also lets me show the user all of the steps that will occur for this install
        // Basically is for creating a progress bar on a web interface and sending it percentages and a message

        if(type == APP_INSTALL || type == BOTH_INSTALL)
        {
            addStep("upload", "Uploading files", &Installer::uploadAppFiles);
        }

        if(type == FILESYSTEM_INSTALL || type == BOTH_INSTALL)
        {
            addStep("upload", "Uploading files", &Installer::uploadFileSystemFiles);
//            addStep("extract", "Uploading files", &Installer::extractTar);
        }

        if(type == APP_INSTALL || type == BOTH_INSTALL)
        {
//            addStep("install", "Install app", &Installer::installAppFiles);
        }

        if(type == FILESYSTEM_INSTALL || type == BOTH_INSTALL)
        {
//            addStep("install", "Install file system", &Installer::installFileSystemFiles);
        }

//        addStep("cleanup", "Cleanup system", &Installer::cleanup);

//        addStep("reboot", "Reboot system", &Installer::reboot);
    }

    void uploadAppFiles() {
//        ...
    }

    void uploadFileSystemFiles() {
//        ...
    }

//    ... other static methods

private:
    QList<Step> m_steps;

    int m_currStep;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you derive your class from QObject and put the functions that you need to call into a "slots" section, then you can use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` to call them by name.